# Set mark when jumping from emacsclient

Tags: emacsclient

I use AucTeX to edit LaTeX files and a PDF viewer that supports inverse search using SyncTeX. When I click on a location in the PDF, it simply calls emacsclient with the corresponding file and line. Often I want to make a quick change and jump back to where I was before. Unfortunately, point is not pushed to the mark ring, so I have to navigate back manually.

Is there any way to have emacsclient set the mark before jumping in an already opened file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give a possible answer to my own question (hope that's ok), here's a solution I just came up with by looking through server.el. It's possible to advise the function that does the jumping:

```
(defun server-goto-line-column@push-mark (orig &rest args)
  (let ((p (save-excursion
             (apply orig args)
             (point))))
    (unless (eq p (point))
      (push-mark))
    (goto-char p)))
(advice-add 'server-goto-line-column :around
            #'server-goto-line-column@push-mark)
```

Comment: This is really a comment on ChrisR's answer, but I am unable to comment for reputation reasons. I found (using emacs 26.3 and auctex 12.1.2) that `TeX-source-correlate-sync-source` rather than `server-goto-line-column` is called when I do an inverse search. Also, I use evil, so I use `evil-set-marker` rather than `push-mark`. Here is the resulting code:
```
(defun TeX-source-correlate-sync-source@set-marker (orig &rest args) (let ((p (save-excursion (apply orig args) (point)))) (unless (eq p (point)) (evil-set-marker ?')) (goto-char p)))
(advice-add 'TeX-source-correlate-sync-source :around #'