# Automatic "push-mark" when navigating with xref, find-grep, etc?

Tags: motion, mark, navigation, grep, xref

There seem to be a lot of situations, where a command changes the cursor location (point), but no mark is pushed, making navigating back by popping the mark with `C-u SPC` impossible.

For isolated use-cases, I can fix this with e.g. `advice-add` on the affected command, or other ad-hoc fixes (see e.g. [Set mark when jumping from emacsclient](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/4079/set-mark-when-jumping-from-emacsclient)). I have however found, that it affects just *too many* situations to manually track down where to put the advice, and maintain that advice as the functions change -- quite often the suitable function is a package-private function like `xref--show-pos-in-buf`.

Examples, where this makes issues, include:

- `M-x xref-...` commands<sup>[1]</sup>
- `M-x occur`
- `M-x grep`
- Latex forward/inverse search
- ...

Is there some better, cleaner way to achieve more comprehensive "mark-pushing"?

## Workflow and Workarounds

Given a setup

```
+--EmacsFrame----------------------+
|              |                   |
| FileBuffer   |  NavigationBuffer |
| FileWindow   |  NavigationWindow |
|              |                   |
|              |                   |
+----------------------------------+
```

Where *NavigationBuffer* is associated e.g. with the `xref`, `diff`, `find-grep`, or `occur` feature, I may either:

1. Switch to *NavigationWindow* with a keyboard command, and activate a command, that causes the point in `FileBuffer` to change, or
2. Click somewhere in *NavigationWindow* to the same effect.

Case (2) can be covered the same way for left-click and right-click events. Many modes however default to reacting only to middle-button clicks; In this case, `selected-window` and `current-buffer` remain the same before and after the command.

While I can probably find a workaround for the middle-click case, the solution seems like a messy workaround at this point; A cleaner solution would be preferable.

## Footnotes

<sup>[1]</sup> [RichieHH's Answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/55320/2308): In this case, there is `M-,` aka `xref-pop-marker-stack`, but setting the mark would still be nice for consistency.

Comment: Can you specify (verbally or by code) the situations where you want the mark set? Clearly you don't want to set it by hand - that's one extreme (which most of us prefer, I think). And (clearly?) you don't want it set for every command that moves point. So something in between - but what, exactly? The question seems vague, so far.

Comment: My strategy is using a point history ring where large point motions are automatically stored. See [pointhistory.el](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/pointhistory).

Comment: There is also https://github.com/boyw165/history/, it's the best solution for this that I've tried so far.

Comment: @Drew Essentially I want to push the mark, whenever navigation in one buffer is triggered by interactive features of another buffer. Phrasing it like that, find these  three events: (a) I switch to another buffer, usually in another window, (b) I perform a left-click on another window, or (c) I perform a middle-click in another window.

Comment: Please put such info into the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time. Questions should stand on their own. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Certaily with xref, Use revert: `M-,` is the default.

xref-pop-marker-stack

> `M-,` (translated from `<escape> ,`) runs the command
>   `xref-pop-marker-stack` (found in `global-map`), which is an interactive
>   compiled Lisp function in `xref.el`.
>
> It is bound to `M-,`, `<menu-bar> <edit> <goto> <xref-pop>`.
>
> `(xref-pop-marker-stack)`
>
> Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 25.1.
>
> Pop back to where `M-.` was last invoked.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I think I even knew the solution for xref before but forgot again; Which is part of why I want consistent behavior across the various use-cases...